# Calculate forces between two flat coils

Tags: electromagnetism, coil

I am trying to estimate forces acting between two sandwiched flat coils, with opposite currents sent through them. This is clearly not my field of expertise and High School is quite some years past and this may be a stupid question, so bear with me.

Suppose I have two flat coils (Archimedean spirals) with some inner and some outer radius and number of turns. From that I can calculate the length of the wires. Now I'm calculating the Lorentz Force that one coil exerts to the other with

$$\vec F_1 = I_2 \left( \vec l \times \vec B_1 \right) $$

and vice versa, where \$ \vec F_1 \$ is the Lorentz Force exerted by coil #1 on coil #2, \$ I_2 \$ is the current in coil #2, \$ \vec l \$ is the length of wires, and \$ \vec B_1 \$ is the magnetic field of coil #1. The magnetic field seems to be

$$\left| \vec B \right| = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}$$

with magnetic constant \$\mu_0\$ and distance between coils \$r\$.

Now when I think about this, this seems to be true for two parallel wires, but I am not sure if this also holds for non-straigth wires, i.e. coils. It's hard to get my head around this; when I wind up my wires into coils, \$ \vec B \$ must be totally different, as there must be many many more interactions between turns of the wires, right? How would I calculate this?

Comment: How the coils are wanted to be placed and rotated in relative each other? That's important because  simpler cases are solvable with simpler calculations. Do you expect a general formula for arbitary coil placements and positions or some special case like "flat in the same plane" or "in parallel planes with common center axis"? I suspect the latter is your wanted special case,

Comment: No, I'm looking for the most basic configuration: both (equally sized) coils ontop of each other, thus parallel and aligned, with some sheet in between, so approx. 1mm distance between the coils.

Comment: Any reason you can't just build them and measure it?

Comment: The point actually was to estimate before building. I would like to get an idea of some metrics of several different coil configurations beforehand, otherwise I'd have to build and measure lots of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force between 2 coils which have current is by no means trivial case. You have got a suggestion to calculate the gradient of the total magnetic field of the coils. That assumes there's a simple translation force which tries to change the relative placements of the coils. If the assumption is true the gradient of the field energy really gives it (or actually negative of the force), when one of the coils is assumed to be fixed and the other can move. The gradient should be calculated by using the displacement coordinates of the movable coil.

Very likely in practice the movable coil tries also to rotate, even to flip. That's because different parts of the coil actually are in different field, so torque is expected.

But if the coil is already rotated as much as it wants and some obstacle prevents the coils to move closer, the force against that obstacle can well be calculated as minus directed derivative of the field energy towards the obstacle (= minus gradient's component in that direction). Actually one can calculate the attraction force to move to certain direction by calculating the inverted directed derivative of the field energy to that direction. Torque can be calculated in the same way, but the displacement must be replaced by rotation angle.

If mechanical obstacles allow only one freedom axis of motion, the force to that direction can be calculated as minus the directed derivative of the field energy to that direction, no matter is the coil already in equilibrium in other axles of freedom or not. For example in motors the mechanic allows only rotation, so to get the torque the field energy derivative is needed only in relative with the rotation angle.

How to calculate the field energy for the force estimation

When there's 2 coils the case seems tricky, but not impossible. If one tries to derive a 2 coil analog for single coil energy 0.5LI^2 by assuming there's some sources connected to both coils which feed some currents which finally reach certain values he gets a sum of three energies:

1) The energy stored into the field of the self-inductance of coil 1

2) The energy stored into the field of the self-inductance of coil 2

3) The energy stored into the common field of the coils

The division to algebraic sum of three energy components is a relief. Terms 1 and 2 do not depend on how the coils are placed in relative each other. Only term 3 determines the force. We skip the circus number "Performing the integration for term 3" and write directly the result:

The common field energy Wab of coils a and b:  **Wab = MIaIb** where M is the mutual inductance, Ia and Ib are the currents of the coils

Let the coils be placed near each other, let they have distance D. Let's assume that the coils have already settled to a certain equilibrium placement and position which mechanical obstacles allow, but it's possible to move one of the coils to direction X without meeting any resistance caused by the mechanical obstacles. Assume the other of the coils is fixed.

For ex. coil a is horizontal, it's glued to the table, coil b is as flat, but above it and the coils have rotated and moved as much they want, only a cardboard sheet thickness = D prevents the coils get closer each other. We want to calculate how much mechanical force is needed to move coil b upwards when the gravity is ignored. X=upwards and only magnetic attraction tries to prevent it, there's no mechanical obstacles.

Calculation: Determine the mutual inductance Md when the distance is D and determine it again, when distance is increased  a little, say 10% of D. Let the new distance be E and the new mutual inductance be Me.

The resistance force is the upwards directed derivative of the energy F=IaIb(Md-Me)/(E-D)

Is this at all useful? No, if you have the coils and they aren't microscopic small. In that case you simply feed some currents and measure the force (remember to subtract the weight)

Measurement of the mutual inductance is tricky but it's possible, so calculation is possible if you have Md and Me.

If everything must be calculated, the coils are only presented as point series or formulas, one can use Neumann's mutual inductance formula:

[image]

The formula is presented and proved in theoretical electricity textbooks. This snippet is taken from Wikipedia article of inductance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance

That vector double integral along coil paths can generally be calculated only numerically. Premium math packages can do it, but one can also use Excel or write the needed program by himself. The practical calculation procedure is out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your very detailled reply. Translating this to Lorentz forces, where F = I (d x B) and B =  mu0 I / (4pi r), I came to something very similar, would you think that this is correct: Fm,n = Im In mu0 / 4pi integral_over_Cm( integral_over_Cn( dxm x dxn / | xm - xn | ) ) ? Note the cross product between dxm and dxn?

Comment: Sorry, it will take some time to be able to render your formulas. Integrated Lorentz force approach is perfectly valid and gives also torque in relative a given axis. But I didn't suggest it because mutual inductance approach gives a theoretical possibility to solve the case with pure electrical measurements. With computer the Lorentz force approach is as work quite the same as calculating M except storing the force elements gives possibilities to find arbitary obstacle and torque cases exactly.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realized it's also possible in comments to use MathJax. Here we go: \$F= I \left( \vec d \times \vec B \right)\$ , \$\vec B =\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi r}\$ and \$F_{m,n}=I_m I_n \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \oint_{C_m} \oint_{C_n} \frac{ \vec{dx_m} \times \vec{dx_n}}{ | x_m - x_n | }\$

Comment: looks right except add distance to the formula of flux density.

Comment: Oh. Yeah. Right. Was a typo, corrected it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It is not so easy to calculate forces with mathematical expressions based on this setup. You would have to integrate the B-field in the coil. You would need to calculate the energy gradient in a 3D setup to get the forces between the coils.

But it is very easy to simulate this setup with a finite element field solver tool. I can recommend [FEMM](http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) for this.

[Here](http://www.femm.info/wiki/MagneticsTutorial) is a tutorial that got me up and running. I must admit that the drawing editor is not easy to get used to. One important thing to know is that you can delete objects with with the right mouse button.to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to FEMM, seems very useful indeed. The coils are placed ontop of each other, aligned at approx. 1 mm distance. Under these circumstances, can't this be greatly simplified by looking at it as a 2D problem? For my use case also a reasonable approximation would suffice, by the way.

Comment: With FEMM, you can select a so called axisymmetric model. You can specify the coils in 2D and FEMM rotates and solves around the center in 3D.

Comment: Seems like I'm not able to figure it out. I've got a spiral with ~150 turns. I converted my SVG to DXF in order to import it to FEMM, however it seems to expect areas, not a path, as it complains about orphaned vertices (beginning and end). I also have to assign materials. IDK, a coil like this will be composed of a terrific amount of vertices and expectedly very heavy to simulate, the import took 10 minutes already. As you said it's "very easy" I am now convinced that I'm not using the tool correctly. Could you kindly point me to some kind of reference or tutorial doing something similar?

Comment: Dont import DXF. Get used to the drawing editor. I added a link to a tutorial in my answer.